# Find first non consecutive element in array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I have a vector, "triggs" with the index number of my triggers. Each trigger lasts several milliseconds and I need to find where each trigger starts.

Put otherwise, I need to find the first element of a consecutive array.
If the vector was:
triggs = [1 2 3 4 5 15 16 17 18 19 20 25 26 27 28 29]

the result I am looking for would have to be: 1, 6, 12.

This is what I usually do:

```
     triggs = find(allChans(2,:)>0.2);
     x = [diff(triggs)~=1,true];
        trigWaves = triggs(x); % This contains the start of each trigger in chan 2
        clear x
        nTrigs = length(trigWaves);
```

The problem is, this is actually finding where each trigger ends and not where it starts.
I have actually done this in the past but can't find the solution anymore.

Comment: So, `find([true diff(triggs)~=1])`?

Comment: Yesss, that's it, thank you Luis :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R2017b, you can do this slightly more simply than using `find(diff(...))` by taking advantage of [`ischange`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischange.html) with the `'linear'` option. You'll still need to prepend a 1. So,

```
>> [1, find(ischange(triggs, 'linear'))]
ans =
     1     6    12
```